# Progress bar doesn't increments its size using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I want to show a progress bar that increments every one second and update the progress bar.

The console shows the counter, but the progress bar is not incrementing its size. I mean it is always a static progress bar.

```js
$(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      counter = counter + 1;
      console.log('Counter: ' + counter); // It works.
      $("#progress").css('width', counter + '%'); // It doesn't work.          
    }, 1000);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div id="progress" class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `counter`s value is over 1000. So you are setting the width to over 1000% ?

Comment: what is in your now textbox - I don't see how it is going to work as your width will always be over 1000%

Comment: $(".progress-bar").css('width', counter + '%');

Answer (score 4):

You can try using pixels, and refer to your progress element with "." because is a class..

```js
$(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(now);
        var counter =0;
        setInterval(function() {
            counter++;
            console.log('Counter: ' + counter); // It works.
            $(".progress").css('width', counter + 'px'); // It doesn't work.          
        }, 1000);

    });
});
```

```css
.progress{
height:10px;
background:red;
width:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
    <div id="barra" class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Do note that there is a html progress tag for this 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where the date is coming into play but your code doesn't work as you are setting the counter to over 1000% width.  The following just shows your code as a simple progress bar that increments 1% every second.

I have added comments as to what I have changed

```js
$(function($) { // this is the same as document ready so you don't need both

  //  $(document).ready(function() {
  // var now = new Date($("#now").text()).getTime();  -- not sure what this is for

  var counter = 0; // make counter global
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#barra").css('width', counter + '%'); // you want to change the width of the inner bar
    counter++; // increment counter
  }, 1000);

  //  });
});
```

```css
#barra {
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div id="barra" class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

You also may want to add a clearInterval once you reach 100

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that there is a height for the wrapper element, but I'm not sure why you're trying to use the actual time from the getTime() call.

I'd strongly recommend using the html5 progress element, but Here's an example using your approach.
L

```
<div class="progress">
<div id="barra" class="progress-bar"></div>
```

CSS

```
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  background: #CCC;
}
.progress .progress-bar {
  background: #27ae60;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
```

JS

```
 $(function($) {

        var now = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(now);
        var counter = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            counter++;
            now + 1000;
            console.log('Counter: ' + now); // It works.
            $(".progress-bar").css('width', counter + '%'); // It doesn't work.          
        }, 1000);

});
```

pen:
https://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/ooBwoy